# How to intercept all http requests in my java app for debug purposes

Tags: java, http, fiddler

I am making a desktop app with Intellij and java. Currently its only few classes. In my app I have several foreign API calls. I want to intercept my calls with some foreign programs like wireshark or fiddler but I cannot. I read the instructions
here: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureJavaApp
or here http://www.asjava.com/tools/capture-http-https-traffic-from-java-programs-with-fiddler/
but they dont work. I generated the certificate, I put it in my keystore, then i put the proxy in my VM options in intellij in the run/debug config and my requests are not shown in Fiddler. Could you help me ? May be there are another apps which works ?

Thanks

Comment: See also mitmproxy.

Comment: Or the Charles proxy.

Comment: tried mitmproxy and it does not work also